# Serve locally using Https

Tags: ionic3

Question 1 :
Is there a way to configure ionic to serve locally using https?
My remote host is SSL and all secure cookies are lost when they come back to the non-SSL browser.

What is the easiest way to solve my problem?

Question 2 :
How to serve Ionic app with https?
Running ionic serve allows to run the app on http://0.0.0.0:8100.

Trying to access https://0.0.0.0:8100 results in:
SSL connection error

Is there a way to run the app on https?